# Retrofit2 Using @QueryMap to Map Objects

Tags: android, retrofit2

I am making a two different service call. One is `/genre/movie/list` and the JSON looks like:

```
{
  "genres": [
    {
      "id": 28,
      "name": "Action"
    },
    {
      "id": 12,
      "name": "Adventure"
    }
]
}
```

This gives me the genreId and the corresponding name. I have another endpoint `discover/movie` which has the following JSON.

```
"results": [
    {
      "vote_count": 263,
      "id": 353081,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 7.5,
      "title": "Mission: Impossible - Fallout",
      "popularity": 465.786,
      "poster_path": "/AkJQpZp9WoNdj7pLYSj1L0RcMMN.jpg",
      "original_language": "en",
      "original_title": "Mission: Impossible - Fallout",
      "genre_ids": [
        12,
        28,
        53
      ],
      "backdrop_path": "/5qxePyMYDisLe8rJiBYX8HKEyv2.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "When an IMF mission ends badly, the world is faced with dire consequences. As Ethan Hunt takes it upon himself to fulfil his original briefing, the CIA begin to question his loyalty and his motives. The IMF team find themselves in a race against time, hunted by assassins while trying to prevent a global catastrophe.",
      "release_date": "2018-07-25"
    },
```

Following are the service calls.

```
@GET("genre/movie/list")
    Observable<HashMap<Integer, Genres>> getMovieGenres(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
@GET("discover/movie")
    Observable<MovieResponse> discoverMovies(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

In discover_movie call, I have an array of genere_ids which gives me the id for the particular genre but it doesn't give me the name. Rather, I am making another service call with the endpoint `genre/movie/list`.

My question is:
How can I use Retrofit2 to Map the id to get the corresponding genre name?

Thank you!

Just to clarify, I have two Pojo:

```
class Movies {
int id;
List<Integer> genre_ids;
}

class MovieGenre {
int id;
String name;
}
```

In the above case, how do I get the genre name corresponding to the genre_ids in a Movie class. The list of genre_ids in movie class is mapped to the id in MovieGrene?

Comment: You need to create two classes for each Json. One for the item (id, name) and another for the List<item> result.

Comment: @HamletLeon I have updated the classes for each JSON. if you look into the movie class, the genre_ids is mapped to the id in MovieGenre class. It is a two different call, how do I get the name now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an Object not a Hashmap for the getMovieGenres Method.

Like this:

```
public class MovieGenres {
    public List<Genres> result;
}
```

Asuming that Genres is like:

```
public class Genres {
     public Integer id;
     public String name;
}
```

And reimplement the method:

```
@GET("genre/movie/list")
    Observable<MovieGenres> getMovieGenres(@Query("api_key") String apiKey);
```

For your last (edited) question, you can do something like this:

```
class MoviesGenreRelation {
    Movie movie;
    List<MovieGenre> genres = new ArrayList<>();

    MoviesGenreRelation(Movie movie, List<MovieGenre> genres) {
        this.movie = movie;
        for(MovieGenre genre in genres) {
            for(int id in movie.genre_ids) {
                if (id == genre.id)
                    this.genres.add(genre);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I updated the POJO. In the meantime, looks like the `genre_id` from `Genres` class is mapped to the `id` Movie class.